# CSV Download not working for all pages

Tags: php, sql-server, csv

I have a website that I created for reports. There are basically 3 reports. I have a button on each page that calls another PHP page that will download the results of the query that fills the page into a CSV file. This works fine on one page, but on the other two it gives me an error when trying to open. It says:

> The file format and extension of 'FileName' don't match. the file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?

I click yes, then get this:

> Excel has detected that 'FileName' is a SYLK file, but cannot load it. Either the file has errors or it is not a SYLK file format. Click OK to try to open the file in a different format.

I click **OK** and it opens fine.

Where as on the other page it just opens.

Here's most of the ExportToExcel.php

```
switch ($_POST['ExportToExcel'])
{
    case "QDef":
        $tsql = "select Id,QSrc,QName,QDef,isActive,RunReport,FilePath from pmdb.v_QDefs order by Id";

        $hsql = "select Headings from TableHeadings where TableName = 'v_QDefs' and Headings != 'Edit' order by ID";

        break;
    case "TableUpdates":
        $tsql = "select ID, TableName, UpdateDate from pmdb.TableUpdates order by UpdateDate";
        $hsql = "select Headings from TableHeadings where TableName = 'TableUpdates' and Headings != 'Edit' order by ID";
        break;
}

$filename = $_POST['ExportToExcel'];

header("Content-Type: application/x-csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.csv");
//define separators (defines columns in excel)
$sep = ",";
$br = "\r\n"; //line break

$getHeadings = $conn->query($hsql);
$rHeadings = $getHeadings->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$headings = array();
$NumHeadings = count($rHeadings);

for ($i = 0;$i < $NumHeadings; $i++)
{
    $headings[] = $rHeadings[$i]["Headings"];
}
//start of printing column names as names of SQL fields
foreach($headings as $Heading => $value)
{
    echo "$value" . $sep;
}
//end of printing column names
echo $br; //separate the headers and the data

foreach($conn->query($tsql) as $row)
{
    for ($i = 0;$i < $NumHeadings;$i++)
    {
        $CommentPos = strpos($rHeadings[$i]["Headings"],"comment");
        $NewLines = array("\r\n","\n\r","\n","\r");
        $UseValue = str_replace($NewLines, " ",$row[$i]);
        $UseValue = str_replace('"', "'",$row[$i]);
        $pos = strpos($UseValue,",");
        if ($CommentPos === FALSE || $pos === FALSE || isset($UseValue))
        {
            echo '"' . $UseValue . '"' . $sep;
        }
        else
        {
            echo $UseValue . $sep . "Not quoted";
        }
    }
    echo $br;
}
```

I have a `include` at the top that has the connection string for connecting to my MSSQL DB, which does work, or there'd be nothing displayed on the page to begin with.

I just con't figure out why the page doesn't work the same way for all reports when they are all calling the page the same way.

**EDIT again**

I tried several ideas from below and now I have this:

```
$filename = $_POST['ExportToExcel'] . '.csv';

$Opened = fopen($filename,'w');

header("Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8'");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");

fputcsv($Opened,$headings);

foreach($conn->query($tsql) as $row)
{
    fputcsv($Opened,$row);
}
fclose($Opened);
```

Which **still** gives me a blank spreadsheet. So obviously I'm still doing something wrong?

Comment: MS Excel will recognise any file that begins with `ID` as a SYLK-format multiplan file; either quote your strings (which would happen if you were using PHP's built-in `fputcsv()` function to write your file, or change the heading value to something other than `ID`

Comment: Using PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function will also ensure that you don't encounter any errors if your strings contain a `,` character, otherwise your homebrew version will break

Comment: Please note, that CSV is not necessarily bound to Excel but merely the abbreviation for **c**omma-**s**eparated **v**alues. Your HTTP header/MIME type is not really wrong, you are using `application/x-csv`. But the RFC says to use `text/csv` for plain CSV files.

If you want to declare it as an Excel sheet, you could also use `application/vnd.ms-excel` for XLS files or `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` for XLSX files.

Comment: @Paul - though of course most recent versions of MS Excel will complain if they receive a csv file with an extension of .xls or .xlsx

Comment: Sure, then you need to create an XLS(X) file, of course. I was just mentioning the correct MIME types for Excel files since OP named his function `ExportToExcel`. There is a library called PHPExcel for that, by the way.

Comment: @MarkBaker I tried adding a `'` to the headings. It adds that to the file when it is opened. I'll have to look into the `fputcsv()`.

Comment: @Paul I'm not able to export to anything other than a CSV unless I get some sort of plugin. Which I'm trying to avoid if I can.

Comment: @Mike Still, try using the correct MIME type `text/csv`, it helped me in similar cases. Also try to open it in LibreOffice for example to detect other issues that may arise with the export files.

Comment: @Paul I did update the mime type. Made no difference in the download. I tried that before I asked the question. I changed it back since it didn't do anything for me. I've put it back now though. Hopefully with the correct type I'll find a solution.

Comment: @MarkBaker I've now tried adding the `fputcsv` in to my file. Now I get a blank file as the output.

Comment: You're creating a file on the server using `$Opened = fopen($filename,'w');`... open `php://output` as your file

Comment: And your'e iterating over each heading in turn passing that to `fputcsv()`.... `fputcsv()` accepts the array of headings as its input, not every individual heading.... similarly for rows.... reading the documentation would have told you this

Comment: @MarkBaker I did read the documentation. I what I thought it said. It does show it iterating, I just misunderstood that it's pulling each line not each value from each line. I've corrected that above and I still get a blank file. And I don't understand what you mean about the open file. I'm trying to export the csv?

Comment: Yes, you're trying to export the csv, not write it to the server, so instead of `$Opened = fopen($filename,'w');` use `$Opened = fopen('php://output','w');`.... that opens the file for writing to the browser, not to a file on your server

Comment: @MarkBaker I think there's still some confusion on my part. I don't want this displayed in the browser I want this written to a file, so why wouldn't I want to open a file on the server? Changing it to be `fopen('php://FileName.csv','w')` just added php--- to the name of the file when opened.

Comment: If you want it written to a file on the server, then why are you sending headers to tell the browser to expect a csv file?

Comment: @MarkBaker That is the way that I found it was done in other posts. I send the headers so that excel knows what it's opening. For the other pages it works fine. Only for these two excel won't open it without the errors. I do not want it displayed in the browser.

Comment: I have figured out part of the problem, but I've no idea how to fix it. When I have `fopen('php://output','wb')` it will work, but if I change the name of the file to `fopen('php://FileName','wb')` it fails to open the file. According to the documentation it should create the file if it doesn't exist, So what's happening? Why can't I name the file?

Comment: The `php://` prefix is identifying a [file stream wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php).... valid file stream wrappers for the `php://` include `input` and `output` but not `FileName`

Comment: I've gotten it to open the file, but `fputcsv` doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: When I `var_dump($Opened);` I get >resource(4) of type (stream), So I know that the stream on the file is being opened. why am I not getting anything added to the file stream with `fputcsv($Opened,$headings);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I updated the Headings for all the tables that I am trying to export so that the first column is no longer `ID`, but is instead `Id`. Since it's no longer all caps it is working fine without the `fputcsv` since that isn't doing anything for me anyhow.

```
$filename = $_POST['ExportToExcel'] . '.csv';

header("Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8'");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");

//define separators (defines columns in excel)
$sep = ",";
$br = "\r\n"; //line break

$getHeadings = $conn->query($hsql);
$rHeadings = $getHeadings->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$headings = array();
$NumHeadings = count($rHeadings);

for ($i = 0;$i < $NumHeadings; $i++)
{
    $headings[] = $rHeadings[$i]["Headings"];
}

//start of printing column names as names of SQL fields
foreach($headings as $Heading => $value)
{
    echo "$value" . $sep;

}

foreach($conn->query($tsql) as $row)
{
    for ($i = 0;$i < $NumHeadings;$i++)
    {
        $CommentPos = strpos($rHeadings[$i]["Headings"],"comment");
        $NewLines = array("\r\n","\n\r","\n","\r");
        $UseValue = str_replace($NewLines, " ",$row[$i]);
        $UseValue = str_replace('"', "'",$row[$i]);
        $pos = strpos($UseValue,",");
        if ($CommentPos === FALSE || $pos === FALSE || isset($UseValue))
        {
            echo '"' . $UseValue . '"' . $sep;
        }
        else
        {
            echo $UseValue . $sep . "Not quoted";
        }
    }
echo $br;
}
```